# Reset all values to default in dynamic array

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

Please look at my code:

```
var
  b: array of Boolean;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetLength(b,3); //All values are False by default
  b[0]:=True;
  //Do something here
  SetLength(b,0);
  SetLength(b,3); 
end;
```

I tested and `b[0]=False`.

My question: Is using `SetLength(b,0)` and then `SetLength(b,n)` the correct way to reset all values to default(False)? 
Is `b[0]=False` in all cases, or `True` in some case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SetLength()` zero-initializes the memory it allocates, so yes, the booleans will always be False by default.

That being said, instead of reallocating the array at all, consider resetting the booleans manually:

```
var
  b: array of Boolean;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: integer;
begin
  SetLength(b,3); //All values are False by default
  b[0] := True;
  //Do something here
  for I := 0 to High(b) do
    b[I] := False; // or Default(Boolean)
end;
```

Or, you can fill the allocated memory with zeroes using `FillChar()` or `ZeroMemory()`:

```
var
  b: array of Boolean;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetLength(b,3); //All values are False by default
  b[0] := True;
  //Do something here
  ZeroMemory(@b[0], Length(b)); // or FillChar(b[0], Length(b), $0);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks you. ZeroMemory look good, is ZeroMemory faster than Loop For? Really i want to reset quickly all values. I usually use `setlength(..,0)` and then `setlength(..,n)` to reset, very fast but i don't know is correct?

Comment: @LuanXa Consider the second option, using `ZeroMemory()`. It is AFAIK the fastest method to reset memory.

Comment: Heap allocation is the slow part. 4 booleans aren't going to be a bottleneck.

Comment: "*is ZeroMemory faster than Loop For?*" - you should profile your code and find out the timing for yourself, but `SetLength(...,0); SetLength(...,n);` is definitely not going to be faster then just filling a memory block that already exists.

Comment: AFAIK; FillChar is the most performant in Windows. Not sure which (ZeroMemory or FillChar) is faster on other platforms. Both are certainly faster than a simple loop or `SetLength(x, 0); SetLength(x, n);`.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis depending on which implementation is used, `ZeroMemory()` is either the Win32 function of the same name, or it is an RTL wrapper that just calls `FillChar()`.